# Nested method calls with &mut receivers result in borrow checker errors

Tags: rust

I ran into an issue when dealing with nested method calls with `&mut` receivers that result in borrow checker errors. Specifically, the `deal` function implemented for the `Table` struct. The `Table` has both `players: Vec<Player>` and a `deck: Vec<Card>`. During `deal`, I am attempting to *move* cards from the `Table`'s `deck` into `Players`s` hands.

```
struct Card {
    value: u32,
}

struct Player {
    name: String,
    hand: Vec<Card>,
}

struct Table {
    players: Vec<Player>,
    deck: Vec<Card>,
}

impl Card {
    fn new(value: u32) -> Card {
        Card { value: value }
    }
}

impl Player {
    fn new<S>(name: S) -> Player where S: Into<String> {
        Player { name: name.into(), hand: Vec::new() }
    }
}

impl Table {
    fn new(players: Vec<Player>) -> Table {
        let deck = vec![
            Card::new(0),
            Card::new(1),
            Card::new(2),
            Card::new(3),
            Card::new(4),
            Card::new(5),
            Card::new(6),
            Card::new(7),
            Card::new(8),
            Card::new(9),
        ];

        Table { players: players, deck: deck }
    }

    fn deal(&mut self) {
        for player in &mut self.players {
            self.hit(player);
            // Table::hit_b(player, &mut self.deck);
            // player.hand.push(self.deck.pop().unwrap());
        }
    }

    fn hit(&mut self, player: &mut Player) {
        player.hand.push(self.deck.pop().unwrap());
    }

    fn hit_b(player: &mut Player, deck: &mut Vec<Card>) {
        player.hand.push(deck.pop().unwrap());
    }

}

fn main() {
    println!("Simplified Playing Card Implementation");

    // Initialization
    let players = vec![
        Player::new("Player 1"),
        Player::new("Player 2"),
        Player::new("Player 3"),
    ];

    let mut table = Table::new(players);

    // Action
    table.deal();

    // Print
    for player in &table.players {
        print!("{}: ", player.name);
        for card in &player.hand {
            print!("{} ", card.value);
        }
        println!("");
    }
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:47:4
   |
46 |            for player in &mut self.players {
   |                               ------------ first mutable borrow occurs here
47 |                    self.hit(player);
   |             ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
48 |                    // player.hand.push(self.deck.pop().unwrap());
49 |            }
   |            - first borrow ends here
```

I have implemented several different workarounds, namely direct in-lining and static functions, that are commented out in for the code in question. Of course, there are many other workarounds that I did not include for brevity's sake.

Is there a idiomatic way to approach the problem of nested method calls with `&mut` receivers? There might be a solution that deals with explicit lifetimes that I am not seeing, but I couldn't quite put a finger on it.

I have also found some relevant issues:

- https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/811
- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6268

As an aside, would anyone be privy to whether this design pattern will be addressed in an upcoming Rust release, maybe related to the improvements seen with MIR?

Comment: There are [**13 other questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+cannot+borrow+%60*self%60+as+mutable+more+than+once+at+a+time+is%3Aq) with the exact same error message. Please [edit] your question to explain why the work that went into all of those answers is insufficient to help you solve your problem. Otherwise, we will just repeat ourselves saying the same thing as those existing answers (or mark this as a duplicate) and you will get no new information.

Comment: Please also check out how to create a [MCVE]. For example, I can guarantee that you don't need to create 10 cards or 3 players to reproduce the error. The smaller the code example, the easier it is to see the problem (both for us and for you).