# One-liner for relative-vector-resizing in Rust

Tags: rust, idioms

If I want to resize a vector in C++/Swift/Any other language I usually write something like this `my_vec.resize(my_vec.size(), 0x00);` but if I try this in Rust I get the error `immutable borrow occurs here`.

Of course I can write something like this:

```
let old_size = my_vec.len();
my_vec.resize(old_size - 2, 0x00);
```

but I'm pretty sure that there is an one-liner...

Comment: Very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352710/nested-method-calls-with-mut-receivers-result-in-borrow-checker-errors

Comment: There is rfc about it: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/811 it would be interesting to know progress on this.

Comment: Is this only to truncate a vector, or are you looking for a solution that can also grow it?

Comment: Im looking for a solution to generally resize a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot currently put the two in lines into one as described in [Cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable in function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41187296/155423).

> but I'm pretty sure that there is an one-liner...

Of course:

```
{ let old_size = my_vec.len(); my_vec.resize(old_size - 2, 0x00); }
```

Less cheekily, you can add a trait method:

```
trait ResizeRelative<T> {
    fn resize_relative(&mut self, delta: isize, default: T);
}

impl<T: Clone> ResizeRelative<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn resize_relative(&mut self, delta: isize, default: T) {
        let len = if delta < 0 {
            self.len() - ((-delta) as usize)
        } else {
            self.len() + delta as usize
        };

        self.resize(len, default);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    v.resize_relative(3, 42);
    v.resize_relative(-1, 2);
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Note the gyrations you need to perform to be able to resize in both directions. Even then, there's still the possibility of panicking if you resize below zero.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the problem... I thought the function was evaluated after the function-parameters; I didn’t realize that the function really got expanded to `Vec::resize(&mut my_vec, ...)`